# Correlation between normal RV and truncated normal RV

Tags: correlation, truncated-normal-distribution

If I have two normally distributed random variables $a\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu_a,\sigma_a\right)$ and $b\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu_b,\sigma_b\right)$ with correlation $\rho$, is there a closed form for the correlation between $a$ and a transformation of $b$:
$$
b^\prime=\begin{cases}
b & \text{if } b\leq\mu_b \\
(1-\eta) b+\eta\mu_b & \text{ if } b>\mu_b
\end{cases},
$$
for some $\eta\in\left[0,1\right]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we assume joint normality (here, it doesn't seem possible to calculate the correlation coef. when we don't have information about the joint distribution), we can use [bivariate normal distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BivariateNormalDistribution.html) for formulating the joint PDF. We need $cov(a,b')$ and $var(b')$.

First, we write $b'$ in terms of indicators as $b'=b\mathcal{I}(b\leq\mu_b)+((1-\eta)b+\eta\mu_b)\mathcal{I}(b>\mu_b)$. Since $\mathcal{I}(b>\mu_b)=1-\mathcal{I}(b\leq\mu_b)$, $b'$ becomes $b'=\eta(b-\mu_b)\mathcal{I}(b\leq\mu_b)+(1-\eta)(b-\mu_b)+\mu_b$. The final term $\mu_b$ is constant and doesn't affect both variance and covariance calculations.

$$\begin{align}cov(a,b') &=\eta cov(a,(b-\mu_b)I(b\leq\mu_b))+(1-\eta)cov(a,b)\\ &= \eta cov(v,u\mathcal{I}(u\leq 0))+(1-\eta)\rho\sigma_a\sigma_b \\ &= \eta E[vu\mathcal{I}(u\leq 0)]+(1-\eta)\rho\sigma_a\sigma_b\end{align}$$
where $u=b-\mu_b$, $v=a-\mu_a$ (de-meaning $a$ doesn't change the covariance). Using joint PDF, ($C=\frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_a\sigma_b\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}$), we can calculate the above expectation term as follows:

$$\begin{align}E[vu\mathcal{I}(u\leq 0)] & = C\int_{-\infty}^0 u\int_{-\infty}^\infty v\exp\left({-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)}\left(\frac{u^2}{\sigma_b^2}-\frac{2\rho uv}{\sigma_a\sigma_b}+\frac{v^2}{\sigma_a^2}\right)}\right)dvdu \\ &= C\int_{-\infty}^0u\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma_b^2}\right)\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}v\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)\sigma_a^2}\left(v-\frac{u\rho\sigma_a}{\sigma_b}\right)^2\right)dvdu \\ &= \frac{1}{2\pi\sigma_a\sigma_b\sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\int_{-\infty}^0u\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma_b^2}\right)\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_a\sqrt{1-\rho^2}\frac{u\rho\sigma_a}{\sigma_b}du \\ &= \frac{\rho\sigma_a}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_b^2}\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}u^2\exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2\sigma_b^2}\right)du=\frac{\rho\sigma_a\sigma_b}{2}\end{align}$$

When we substitute:
$$cov(a,b')=\boxed{\frac{(2-\eta)}{2}\rho\sigma_a\sigma_b}$$

For the variance, we use a similar method with variable changes and ignoring constant terms: $$\begin{align}var(b') &=cov(b',b')=cov(\eta u \mathcal{I}(u\leq 0)+(1-\eta)u,\eta u \mathcal{I}(u\leq 0)+(1-\eta)u) \\ &= (2\eta-\eta^2)E[u^2\mathcal{I}(u\leq 0)]-\eta^2E[u\mathcal{I}(u\leq 0)]^2+(1-\eta)^2E[u^2]\end{align}$$

Calculating the terms:
$$E[u^2\mathcal{I}(u\leq 0)]=\int_{-\infty}^0u^2f(u)du=\frac{1}{2}E[u^2]=\frac{\sigma_b^2}{2}$$
$$E[u\mathcal{I}(u\leq 0)]=\int_{-\infty}^0u\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma_b}\exp\left(\frac{-u^2}{2\sigma_b^2}\right)du=-\frac{\sigma_b}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \text{when  } \alpha=\frac{u^2}{2\sigma_b^2}$$
Substituting yields the following weird formula:
$$var(b')=\sigma_b^2\left(\frac{(1-\eta)^2+1}{2}-\frac{\eta^2}{2\pi}\right)\rightarrow \rho_{a,b'}=\boxed{\rho\frac{2-\eta}{\sqrt{4-4\eta+2\eta^2(1-1/\pi)}}}$$

which changes in $\approx [0.856\rho,\rho]$.

Note: numerically verified.